# Apache Spark - Feature Extraction Word2Vec example and exception

Tags: python, scala, exception, apache-spark, word2vec

**A. Following is my configuration:**

OS: Windows 7

Spark version: 1.4.1 (issue also present in 1.4.0)

Language: Python and Scala both

**B. Example source code:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec

sc = SparkContext(appName='Word2Vec')
inp = sc.textFile("news2.txt").map(lambda row: row.split(" "))
word2vec = Word2Vec()
model = word2vec.fit(inp)  #Results in exception...
```

**C.Following is the stack trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/StudySpark/Projects/Example/poc/poc5/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = word2vec.fit(inp)
  File "E:\StudySpark\Projects\Example\spark1.4.1\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\feature.py", line 519, in fit
  File "E:\StudySpark\Projects\Example\spark1.4.1\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\common.py", line 128, in callMLlibFunc
  File "E:\StudySpark\Projects\Example\spark1.4.1\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\common.py", line 121, in callJavaFunc
  File "E:\StudySpark\Projects\Example\spark1.4.1\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "E:\StudySpark\Projects\Example\spark1.4.1\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.trainWord2Vec.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.head(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2VecModel.<init>(Word2Vec.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainWord2Vec(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any clues?

Best Regards,

Vishal

Comment: Can you please show the format of your input file?

Comment: I tried two formats...one has air oxygen breathe in a single line...the other has air oxygen breathe one in each line (3 lines)...Also tried with more words on a single line / multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Bacon. You set me on the right path.

Input file did not have words that repeated a certain number of times in the input. By default the minimum count for the token to appear in word2vec model is 5 (look at class word2vec in feature.py under YOUR_INSTALL_PATH\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\feature.py)

My reading, error message could have been better.

Best Regards,
Vishal